# Vue, do I need the colon for all my functions?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In the Vue documentation, the syntax `myFunc: function(){...}` is often used, for `computed` or `methods`. In these places, `myFunc(){...}` also works. Is there any difference? Is there any reason not to use the simpler syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The both do the same thing. The difference is the shorter one is ES6 syntax which needs to be transpiled into ES5 in order to work in older browsers.